# Transalting an aws cli bucket command to boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I am able to get an aws CLI command working.

The structure is as follows:

```
(base) USER@USER-MS-7A37:~/some_dir$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [*******************Q]: FOOOOOQ
AWS Secret Access Key [*******************t]: FOOOOOt
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

Followed by:

```
(base) USER@USER-MS-7A37:~/some_dir$ aws s3 ls s3://whatIwasGiven/ByVendor/
```

Which yields:

```
PRE BUCKETCONTENTS/
```

And in `BUKCETCONTENTS`, there's `stuff`.

Now, I am trying to get things working in python3 with `boto3 (boto3==1.16.0)`.

My current code looks like the following:

```
import boto3
ACCESS_KEY =  'FOOOOOQ'
SECRET_KEY = 'FOOOOOt'
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='whatIwasGiven/ByVendor/')
```

Which yields a `ParamValidationError`.

What is the correct format for my CLI request using boto3?

Answer (score 0):

You need adding Prefix key with folder name:

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='whatIwasGiven',
                                  Prefix='ByVendor')

for key in response['Contents']:
    print(key['Key'])
```